# Mithril filtering list of components

Tags: components, filtering, mithril.js

I've encountered a problem when trying to filter a list of data using mithril.js.

I've got two components: a form and an inputWrapper.

- The form shows a form with multiple input fields that each has a value.
- The form also has a search-input that allows to filter the data.

When directly using `m('input', { value: ...} )` in the form view, filtering works beatifully.

When using a component that contains an input and an `m.prop` coupled to its value, everything goes amis. 
In the form we have something like: `m.component( inputWrapper, { value: ... })` 
When trying to filter this list, the view renders the wrong components.

Have look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/steviewondrs/pen/jrVdWL?editors=0010) to get a clearer picture.

My guess is that the mithril diff engine stores a set of cached components and renders these instead of instantiating new ones on each redraw.
Yet, I haven't found a solution for getting this right. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to refactor your code a bit to be able to follow the logic, but managed to get it working.

The caching issue is to do with controllers: upon redraw, if a component of a given type renders in the same place as a component of the same type was in the previous draw — *and the components do not have a distinguishing key* — then it is assumed you want to retrieve the previous controller. And in the case of your component, the controller stores the input to be used by the view (instead of the view reading it directly from its own `args` input).

The easiest way to solve this is to simply get rid of the controller and read the input directly, since it serves no desirable purpose if the input should always be fresh.

```js
// ---------------------------------
//     component with an input
// ---------------------------------
const inputWrapper = {
 view : ( ctrl, args ) =>    
  m('input[type=text]', args )
}

// ---------------------------------
//    component that filters list
// ---------------------------------
m.mount( document.body, {
 controller : function( attrs ) {
  const filterTerm = m.prop( '(?:)' )
  
  return { 
   filterTerm, 
   filterFunc : word => {
    const term = filterTerm()
    
    if ( _.isString( term ) && _.isString( word ) )
     return word.search( new RegExp( term, 'i' ) ) > -1
   }, 
   someData : [ "long", "list", "of", "meaningful", "data", "really", "cool", "stuff"]
  }
 },
 
 view : ( { filterTerm, filterFunc, someData }, attrs ) =>
  m('form',
   m('p',
    m('input[type=text]', {
     oninput     : m.withAttr( 'value', filterTerm ),
     placeholder : 'filter data'
    })
   ),
   
   m('p',
    m('ul',
     someData
      .reduce( ( acc, val ) =>
       ( ( filterTerm() && filterTerm() == '/(?:)/' ) || filterFunc(val) )
       ? acc.concat( val )
       : acc, 
      [] 
      )
      .map( value => 
       m('li',
        m('input',      { value } ),
        m(inputWrapper, { value } )
       )
      )
    )
   )
  )
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/0.2.5/mithril.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, this fix reveals other problems: because the data that generates the list (and the components) is created on the fly in each draw, the data structure that the inputs would bind to is simply disposed of on each redraw, when a new array is generated from the reduce and map functions in the parent component.

The solution to that problem would be to perform the reduction in the parent controller that receives the data, such that it can be retrieved in the next draw.

Other little tweaks that I made to the code:

- The array brackets for virtual DOM children in the view are unnecessary (I removed a lot more punctuation, out of personal preference :).
- The destructuring you were performing in `let` assignments can be performed in the function arguments signature, reducing verbosity.
- Removing these assignments allows the 'implicit return' form of arrow function expression, which makes it easier to see the structure of the view output while removing the number of variables to think about.
- Using `const` instead of `let` makes it clear that the values being assigned to references cannot change, which makes it easier to find where code might be doing something unexpected.
- Reducing the reduce expression's callback to a ternary makes it clear there is only 1 logical condition and 2 possible outcomes, and `concat` allows you to produce a new structure in a single expression (instead of `push`ing and *then* `return`ing.

Answer (score 0):

After yet another round of digging through mithril's documentation I'm here to answer my own question.

If I had provided a *key* when initialising my component:

`m.component( InputWrapper, { key: 'distinguishingKey', value: ... } )`

Things would've worked just fine.

Thanks, Barney, for the hint:

> ...and the components do not have a distinguishing key — ...

And to Leo Horie for providing excelent documentation. (If only I read this weeks ago...)
http://mithril.js.org/mithril.component.html#data-driven-component-identity